# Alinear lista de números decimales en Java

Tags: java

Tengo la siguiente lista de números:

```
100,11
35,00
43,20
5,60
3,00
```

y quiero eliminar los ceros innecesarios y alinear la coma decimal de la siguiente forma:

```
100,1
 35
 43,2
  5,6
  3
```

He probado con:

```
DecimalFormat formato = new DecimalFormat("###.##");
```

y el resultado es:

```
100,1
35
43,2
5,6
3
```

Probando con:

```
DecimalFormat formato = new DecimalFormat("000.##");
```

el resultado es:

```
100,1
035
043,2
005,6
003
```

que se acerca a lo que quiero pero me sobran los ceros a la izquierda

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Comment: Para tener dicho formato es necesario decirle a Java que rellene con espacios para que tenga n cantidad de caracteres ,así se verán alineados. `String.format("%5.1f", numero)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizando expresiones regulares se me ha ocurrido un código mucho más compacto y más versátil ya que sirve para cualquier tamaño de número:

```
    /**
     * Formatea un número añadiendo caracteres para que tenga un tamaño determinado.
     * @param número Es el número double que queremos formatear
     * @param dígitosEntero Es el tamaño en dígitos que deseamos para la parte entera
     * @param dígitosDecimal Es el tamaño en dígitos que deseamos para la parte decimal
     * @param nuevoCaracter Es el caracter que utilizaremos como relleno
     * @return devuelve una cadena con el número formateado
     * Si el número es más largo que los dígitos especificados se devuelve la parte
     * decimal truncada.
     */

private String formatearLectura2(double número, int dígitosEntero, int dígitosDecimal, char nuevoCaracter){       

    String[] parte = String.valueOf(número).split("\\.");    
    String resultado = String.format("%1$" + dígitosEntero + "s",parte[0]);        

    if (parte.length>1){  
        if (Long.parseLong(parte[1])>(long)0) {
            if (parte[1].length()>= dígitosDecimal){
                resultado += "," + parte[1].substring(0, dígitosDecimal);
            } else {
                resultado += "," + String.format("%1-$" + dígitosDecimal + "s",parte[1]);
            }
        }
    }       
    return resultado.replace(' ', nuevoCaracter);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

prueba con de la siguiente manera:

```
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("00.00 bytes");
System.out.print(String.format("%15s", formatter.format(<TU-VARIABLE-DOUBLE>)));
```

Al menos a mi me funcionó. El siguiente ejemplo es lo que probé:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    double num1 = 125.52;
    double num2 = 12;
    double num3 = 1.5;
    DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("00.00 bytes");
    System.out.print(String.format("%15s", formatter.format(num1)));
    System.out.print(String.format("%15s", formatter.format(num2)));
    System.out.print(String.format("%15s", formatter.format(num3)));
 }
```

La salida fue:

```
125.52
12.00
1.50
```

Ahora si es de tu gusto, habria que alinearlos a la derecha (o no, segun lo que necesites). Espero te sirva

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con el siguiente código. No sé si es la mejor solución pero funciona. Sobre todo utiliza una fuente monospace (por ejemplo: Consolas)

```
 public String formatear(double número){        
    // Quito los ceros de la derecha y los de la izquierda y los sustituyo por espacios
    // para que funcione bien tenemos que poner texto monospace

    DecimalFormat formato = new DecimalFormat("000.00"); // definimos formato         
    String entero = "", decimal = "", resultado = "";

    String númeroCadena = String.valueOf(formato.format(número));

    // Quito los ceros de la izquierda
    for (int i=0; i<númeroCadena.length(); i++){

        if (i<númeroCadena.length()-1){
            if (númeroCadena.charAt(i) == '0' && númeroCadena.charAt(i+1)!=','){
                // quitamos cero a la izquierda
                entero += " ";
            } else {
                entero += númeroCadena.substring(i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // Ahora hacemos lo mismo pero de derecha a izquierda por el final       
    for (int i=entero.length()-1; i>0; i--){

        if (i>0){
            if (entero.charAt(i) == '0'){
                // quitamos cero a la derecha
                decimal = " " + decimal;
            } else {                  
                if (entero.charAt(i) == ',' ){
                   resultado = entero.substring(0,i) + decimal +" ";
                   break;
                }
                resultado = entero.substring(0,i+1) + decimal;
                break;
            }
        }
    }        

    if (resultado.length()==0) resultado = entero;
    return resultado; // contiene el número formateado
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo aquí una solución que puede ser de ayuda.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Double[] lista = {100.11,35.00,43.20,5.60,3.00};
        imprimir(lista);
    }

    private static void imprimir(Double[] lista) {
        for (int i = 0;i<lista.length;i++) {
            String str = String.format("%5.1f\n",lista[i]);
            if(str.contains(",0")) {
                str = str.replace(",0", "");
            }
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }
```

Dandole un formato de un solo decimal puedes quitarte el problema y de esta forma se puede quitar el 0 con un replace en caso de ser un número entero.
El código anterior produce la siguiente salida.

```
100,1

35

43,2

5,6

3
```